# How to use compareTo() method to compare objects in a List?

Tags: java, list, compare, nodes

I have a class called `ListNode` that works like a list. Using this class I want to establish a list of Magazine objects. In my `MagazineList` class I want to edit the add method so when I insert `Magazine`s they will be sorted alphabetically. How can I do this?

My `ListNode` class:

```
    public class ListNode {
      private Object value;
      private ListNode next;

      //intializes node
      public ListNode (Object initValue, ListNode initNext) {
       value = initValue;
       next = initNext;
      }

    //returns value of node
    public Object getValue () {
      return value;
    }

     //returns next reference of node
    public ListNode getNext () {
       return next;
    }

     //sets value of node
    public void setValue (Object theNewValue) {
      value = theNewValue;
    }

    //sets next reference of node
    public void setNext (ListNode theNewNext) {
       next = theNewNext;
    }
   }
```

my `MagazineList` class's add method:

```
    //when instantiated, MagazineList's  list variable is set to null
    public void add (Magazine mag) {

      ListNode node = new ListNode (mag, null);
      ListNode current;

      if (list == null)
         list = node;
      else {
         current = list;
         while (current.getNext() != null)
            current = current.getNext();
         current.setNext(node);
      }
   }
```

I used this method to compare the `Magazines` in the `Magazine` class:

```
 //compares the names (Strings) of the Magazines.
  public int compareTo(Magazine mag2) {
     return (title).compareTo(mag2.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to keep your list always sorted.

Then, each time you insert a new node,  starting from the head, you should compare the the new node with each node in the list using `compareTo` method, and insert the new node after the node for which `compareTo` returns positive.

A basic implementation may be like this. You need to improve it and consider edge cases etc. though.

```
//when instantiated, MagazineList's  list variable is set to null
public void add (Magazine mag) {

   ListNode node = new ListNode (mag, null);
   ListNode current;

   if (list == null)
     list = node;
   else {
    current = list; // you list head
    while (node.compareTo(current) < 0)
       current = current.getNext();
   ListNode next = current.getNext();
   current.setNext(node);
   node.setNext(next);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have to complete it with this specific implentation, however...

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
//compares the names (Strings) of the Magazines.
public int compareTo(Magazine mag2) {
    //assume that you have getTittle() method which returns Title
    return title.compareTo(mag2.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: How this method is different from SO has mentioned.

Comment: I want to use the compareTo() method in the add() function of the other class, though. How would I do that?